# Get Image From Image view and send This image to other fragment with encode bitmap

Tags: java, android, bitmap, imageview

i want get image From server and put to this image view i want get image from this imageview and compress with bitmap and send this picture to other fragment i dont want add 2 request for my server

my code is :

```
     Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),"my problem");
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
            mBundle.putByteArray("ResID", byteArray);
```

i know if i put R.darwable.ic_luncher it will work 
but i want take this image from image view and put to " my probem "
can u help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `mImageView.getDrawable()` to get `Drawable` object from `ImageView`:

```
Drawable drawable = mImageView.getDrawable();
```

After that you can obtain a `Bitmap` object from it:

```
BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable);
Bitmap bitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
```

and further, if you want, even `InputStream` for byte array to send it:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
// Here, the CompressFormat and quality can be adjusted for output image size
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
byte[] imageBytes = stream.toByteArray();
ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageBytes);
```

As a result, `imageBytes` will contain all the bytes of the image, which you can send over elsewhere (in your scenario: to your other `Fragment`)